# React Redux Toolkit: Is it okay to write to localStorage in createSlices "reducers" parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I'm implementing a simple favorites list. Currently there's no backend part so it will be persisted in localStorage. In the future it may become an API call.

Is it okay to call `localStorage.setItem`
and `localStorage.getItem` from within a `rtk slice`?

For example:

```
createSlice({
  name: "slice",
  initialState,
  extraReducers: extraReducers,
  reducers: {
    setLocalStorageThing: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<{ payload: string }>
    ) => {
      let localStoragething= JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem("key")
      );
      if (localStorageThing !== payload) {
        localStorage.setItem(
          "key",
          JSON.stringify(payload)
        );
      }
    },
 }
```

Alternatively, is this possible as a `thunk`? Ultimately I'd like to be able to use the `useSelector` hook to access this information, so when the swap happens I only have to change the action/reducer in the slice. This seems like a side effect, but I'm not sure the harm in it. It has already been done else where in the code without issue (so far).

Comment: It is definitly ok ; although you would rather want to initialize the reducer state with the local storage & update your reducer state in the reducer then have a listener updating the local storage when needed

Comment: Do you still have the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to deal with localStore inside reducers because they must be pure https://redux.js.org/understanding/thinking-in-redux/three-principles. You can use a thunk to deal with it

Answer (score 1):

Writing logic for local storage inside reducers will not break the application. But **it breaks the rules of writing reducers**, i.e reducers should not cause **"side effects"**. See the rules [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#rules-of-reducers). In short, it means try to make reducers be all concerned about redux. One way to solve your problem in sync with redux recommendations, is to use a middleware before a particular action type has been run.